# PHP variable containing iframe with dynamic src?

Tags: php, html, iframe, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF on my site, and trying to set up a PHP variable that is an iframe containing an ACF field.

I can't work out why this won't work, because I can echo the variable and it shows, but it spits src(unknown) otherwise?

```
// Get spotify and set up tab
if (have_rows('roster_media')):
    // loop through the rows of data
    while (have_rows('roster_media')): the_row();
        $spotify_uri = get_sub_field('rm_sp_link');
        echo $spotify_uri;
        $url = $spotify_uri;
        echo $url;
    endwhile;
else:
// no rows found
endif;

$rm_sp = '<iframe src="'.$url.'" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>';
```

Then later in the page I'm calling via:

```
<?php

$count = 0;
foreach ($embed_links as $e) {

    if ($count==0) {
        $rm_act = " active show";
    } else {
        $rm_act = "";
    }

    $content;

    if ($e['embed_platform']['value'] === "rm_sp") {
        $content ='<div class="rm-video">'.$rm_sp.'</div>';   
    } else if ($e['embed_platform']['value']==="rm_vid") {
        $content = '<div class="rm-video">'.$rm_vid.'</div>';
    }

    echo '<div class="tab-pane'.$rm_act.'" id="'.$e['embed_platform']['value'].'" role="tabpanel">'.$content.'</div>';
    $count++;
}

?>
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, I'm currently using jQuery (I don't think this is the best way but it's what works for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this is the worst way to do this, but it's currently working for me as I've got no other ideas. I'm using jQuery to achieve this.

In the while loop, I've added:

```
$spotify_uri = get_sub_field('rm_sp_link');
echo '<div id="spot_id">'.$spotify_uri.'</div>';
```

Then my jQuery looks like this:

```
  if ($("#spot_id")[0]){
    // Do something if class exists
    spotifyUri = $("#spot_id").text();
    console.log(spotifyUri);
    $("#spot_iframe").attr('src' , $("#spot_iframe").attr('src') + spotifyUri);
  } else {
      // Do something if class does not exist
  }
```

Obviously, #spot_id also needs to be hidden from users.